# Salvattore does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Attempting to use salvattore.(min).js to implement columns but the javascript does not work unless I inline the salvattore.js code in the <head> element.

Here is my test.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type='text/css'>
#grid[data-columns]::before {
  content: '3 .column.size-1of3';
}

/* These are the classes that are going to be applied: */
.column { float: left; }
.size-1of1 { width: 100%; }
.size-1of2 { width: 50%; }
.size-1of3 { width: 33.333%; }


@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #grid[data-columns]::before {
            content: '1 .column.size-1of1';
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    #grid[data-columns]::before {
            content: '2 .column.size-1of2';
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #grid[data-columns]::before {
            content: '2 .column.size-1of2';
    }
}

/* Again, youre free to use and define the classes: */
.column { float: left; }
.size-1of1 { width: 100%; }
.size-1of2 { width: 50%; }
.size-1of3 { width: 33.333%; }
    </style>
    <script src='/salvattore.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grid" data-columns>
      <div>Item #1</div>
      <div>Item #2</div>
      <div>Item #3</div>
      <div>Item #4</div>
      <div>Item #5</div>
      <div>Item #6</div>
      <div>Item #7</div>
      <div>Item #8</div>
      <div>Item #9</div>
      <div>Item #10</div>
      <div>Item #11</div>
      <div>Item #12</div>
      <div>Item #13</div>
      <div>Item #14</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The salvattore.(min).js is loading and running, in so far as it is changing the ::before pseudo element as the window is squeezed, but the Item divs are displaying as block so rendered as a vertical list (no matter how I resize the window).

I notice that if I replace the <script> tag with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ... cut and paste salvatorre.js (not the min.js) here ...
</script>
```

it works, but this is obviously bad form. I am testing in Chrome and IE and neither work. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please, if you cannot answer the question, do not waste time editing it. I need help with the answer not the question.

Comment: I have found the answer! Undocumented on the salvattor site is the fact you must include the javascript after the grid html. Preferably just before the </body> tag.

Comment: Also the salvattore javascript looks for style or link elements with the "type" attribute explicitly set to "text/css". If you say "<style>...</style>" it does not pick it up.

Answer (score 5):

In case you're still looking for the answer... I found that I need to include the salvattore.min.js just before closing the body tag :) Rather than in the header.

```
<script src="js/salvattore.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```